# Windows 7 taskbar looks weird

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

Does anyone know what happens to my windows 7 taskbar? It looks really weird.

[image: windows 7 taskbar error]

I guess it might have something to do with [Windows 7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) that I have installed on my computer. I've been using that program for about a year without any problems, the problem occur just recently.

I've disabled that program but the problem is still not solved yet. It still looks weird.

Comment: Right click on the Task Bar and in the Properities choose Always Combine, hide labels.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reverse what is shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/make-the-windows-7-taskbar-work-more-like-windows-xp-or-vista/):

1. Right click on the task bar.
2. Choose "Properties".
3. For "Taskbar buttons", choose "Always combine, hide labels".
4. Uncheck "Use small icons".
5. Click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

You can do a System Restore using a Checkpoint before the issue started